# How to show a Popover from the barButtonItem that is in a bar attached to the UIKeyboard

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uipopovercontroller, uikeyboard

[Image here](http://img15.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110405at424.png/)!

Hey guys,

I have Toolbar attached to the keyboard as an accessory view.

```
[textView setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
```

It has a `barButtonItem`. I need to show a `popOver` from the button. I know to use

```
presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
```

but this makes the `popOver` show in weird orientations. I tried various hacks but no luck. Anyone had such issue before?

Code to create PopOverController.

```
- (void) audioRecord:(id)sender event:(UIEvent*)event
{ 

UIBarButtonItem *audioBarButtonItem = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
     if(audioInputController == nil)
    {
        audioVC=[[AudioTextViewController alloc] init];
        audioVC.delegate = self;

        self.audioInputController=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:audioVC];

        CGSize audioViewSize = audioVC.view.frame.size;

        audioInputController.delegate = self;

        [self.audioInputController setPopoverContentSize:audioVC.view.frame.size];

        [audioInputController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:audioBarButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
    }        
}
```

Comment: Show us a screenshot, please.

Comment: here is the screenshot http://img15.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110405at424.png/

Comment: Is the viewController within the popOverController able to rotate? -> Does the viewController support your current orientation?

Comment: Yes. This is what its interface orientation del call back is overrriden to - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

Comment: What does happen if you rotate the sim/device while the popover is showing?

Comment: goes into weird orientations. Never takes the present device orientation. I wonder if UIKeyboard window's orientation is something that is different from the device orientation.

Comment: Hmm hard to tell. Can you give us some code how the popover is created and what goes into it?